# I'm having troubles understanding the logic when using for loops with eventlisteners in javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am learning web development and right now i'm working on  vanilla javascript. I'm following a class on Udemy and everything is going well but there is a challenge where we are supposed to build a drumkit so everytime we click on a button it should trigger a function. So the solution the instructor is giving is using a for loop

```
var nbButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

for(i = 0; i<nbButtons; i++){
    document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
            
    function handleClick() {
        alert("I got clicked!" + i);
    }
}
```

So if I try to analyze the code I understand than :

We create a variable to keep track of the number of .drum elements       (querySelectorAll(".drum") returns an array of all .drum elements and we get it's length.
We start a loop : We start listening for clicks on the .drum element whose number is equal to i and start the function handleClick.

So I tried it and it works but I don't understand why. the loop starts when the page is loaded which means i = nbButtons very quickly (i added console.log in the loop and it does) so logically it should listen only on clicks on the last element ?

I know i'm missing something but I don't know what.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We start listening for clicks on the .drum element whose number is equal to i and start the function handleClick.

This is the part you misunderstood.
You don't immediately start listening to the current element. This line **registers** the listener which then listens more or less in the background. So in your `for` loop you register an event listener for each array index. The event listener isn't overwritten on the next iteration. You're able to register multiple event listeners at once, even on the same element.

You can verify that in devtools:

---

[image: Screenshot DevTools]

---

More information on what `addEventListener()` does: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: Oh ok it makes total sense now, I did assume each one was replacing the previous one. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @altho No problem! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

`nbButtons` is just the number of buttons, say 5 buttons.

Then you use a `for` loop to go through all the 5 buttons. The loop executes 5 times, and this number is temporarily stored in the `i` variable. So, using i you can also get to each button and add the event listener to that button.

You can log this with

```
for(i = 0; i<nbButtons; i++){
    console.log(i);
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several parts of your code that I would write differently (some pointed out in other answers), but the key problem is that you have a global variable `i`, which will already have the value `nbButtons` by the time any of the `handleClick` functions actually run - so it's no surprise that this is the value you see logged on each click.

To make sure the correct value of `i` is logged for each button, you have to ensure the function you add as the event handler actually uses the "current" value. Here is one way:

```
var nbButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

for(let i = 0; i<nbButtons; i++){
    document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() { handleClick(i);} );
} 

function handleClick(i) {
    alert("I got clicked!" + i);
}
```

There are a few key differences from your faulty code. For one, I've pulled the definition of the `handleClick` function out of the loop - this doesn't actually matter here (`function` declarations are scoped to functions, not arbitrary blocks like loops), but is neater and matches better how the code actually behaves. More importantly, I've made it take a parameter, `i`, and made sure the correct `i` is passed in in each `addEventListener` call.

And most importantly of all, I've replaced your global variable `i` in the loop with a local one, declared with `let`. This ensures that when the button is clicked and the function - `function() { handleClick(i);}` is called, it sees not a global `i` whose value was long ago incremented past the intended value, but one scoped to the particular loop iteration, which therefore only ever had the one value. Note that `let` is crucial to make this work, using `var` would not (without some extra complications anyway) - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) classic question for more detail

Comment: Thank you, i'm looking into your link.

Answer (score -1):

What you have done in your for loop is search for a ".drum" using the queryselectorall function which I do not think is efficient - if you must loop with "for";

I think you should:
var nbButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");
var nbButtonsLen= nbButtons.length;

```
for(i = 0; i<nbButtonsLen; i++){
    nbButtons[i].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
}
function handleClick() {
    alert("I got clicked!" + i);
}
```

Comment: While I agree it's better rewritten this way, this does nothing to address the actual problem.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why it is better to do this way ?

Comment: Basically so your script doesn't have to keep computing `document.querySelectorAll(".drum")` every time through the loop. And you don't have to type it more than once!